# Create Restful WCF for iOS

Tags: objective-c, wcf, rest

The iOS code, which is consuming my WCF is:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
//#import "AFNetworking.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)submitBtnPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *sturl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://servername/authentication/login"];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:sturl];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"userName": @"chanml",
                                 @"password": @"password"
                                  };
    [manager POST:sturl parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
     }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation operation, NSError error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];

}
@end
```

The WCF code is:

```
public interface Iauthentication
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();


    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                             RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                             ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                             BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                             UriTemplate = "login")]
                             ////UriTemplate = "login?userName={userName}&password={password}")]
    ResponseData GetLoginData();


    //string GetLoginData(string userName, string password);


}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
public class RequestData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string userName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string password { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ResponseData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string username { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }

}
```

When iOS is consuming this WCF, it replies with `400 bad request`. When they are consuming it without parameter (just calling the method without input parameters), it's OK. I think there may be some parameter type issue.

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

seems like that your contract and service implementation is not matching .but still not sure .

i am not much familiar with ios code, not able to guide you more on that part .

You would already did try with couple of options ,but for other readers let me try to put some steps for debugging .

- try with Fiddler. is fiddler also giving same error ? ( some good link : http://www.paulkiddie.com/2012/02/you-get-a-http-400-bad-request-when-posting-to-a-wcf-service/ )
- Enable WCF tracing . ( link : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx )
- check your wcf service is working fine or not.
- check with innerException message
  -

Comment: This Wcf is working fine from my test application (I have made a test application and tried to consume this wcf).
Even, it's working fine when Ios application is consuming the same, without parameters.